# Make function to List-Comprehension

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension

I have several lines in my code that look very similar to

```
[this.Attribute for this in THAT if something]
```

Is there a way to make a function to return that in a shorter way? Because it gets very tedious creating them and I don't find them so readable especially if there's too many 'if-conditions'.

edit:

Well, I often spend time trying to get something from a big list meeting certain criteria. And I often need to change the criteria and the output. 
Like so:

```
[obj for obj in Object.ALLOBJECTS if obj.pos == (x,y)]

[creature.pos for creature in Creature.ALLCREATURES if creature is not caller]

[creature for creature in Creature.ALLCREATURES if creature.pos == pos and creature is not caller]
```

And so on.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong from the start.

Comment: Can you paste more code to make your question more clear?

Comment: There are lots of potential solutions (involving some combination of `itertools.ifilter`, `itertools.imap`, `operator.attrgetter`, the built-in functions `all` and `any`), but without a more specific question, it's hard to suggest a good solution. What you've posted is actually pretty clear. Wrapping something this simple in a function just adds the overhead of calling a function without adding much clarity, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could outsource the conditional to a function. If it's complex, that
would split up the complexity and make each part easier to read, which
is more or less the point of functions in the first place.